# html input button text

Tags: html, button, text, input

What I want to do is to include a small table as the display text on a button.

My button is set to be 15% of the screen width and 25% of the height with various other styling features done using css.

Assuming this can't be done, could anyone suggest an alternative I can investigate please?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You are correct in your assumption that button/input elements cannot contain table elements. If you can provide more details about your goal, we may be able to provide an alternative suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing this is a case where you might want to re-think what you're trying to do, rather than use a questionable hack to get it working.

Comment: @George: um, [actually a `button` *can* contain a `table`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VbYK9/). But still: it's (very probably) a bad idea, and should not be done.

Comment: You can simulate a button with a div, plus css, and inside it put your table. If it is like a table of menu try use ul li components.

Comment: @DavidThomas The W3 validator says "Element table not allowed as child of element button in this context." Some browsers may handle it, but the specification does not allow it. See the "Permitted parent elements" section of the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html) for more details.

Comment: @George: I wasn't claiming it was *valid* just that it can be done. (Even when it shouldn't.) =)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code with w3c validator with HTML 4.01 Strict doctype:

```
<button>
    <table>
     <tr>
        <td>submit</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
</button>
```

and it is valid.